# mysql interrupt myisamchk and re-run it later?

Tags: mysql

I'm running myisamchk to one table using SSH terminal on my laptop, I need to leave soon and it seems like it's taking a bit longer then I expected, is there a way to sort of interrupt it and re-run it under screen or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move a process into a screen session, but you can background it and then disown the process with `disown <pid>`, which will stop the process from dying when you logout.

SEE ALSO

`bash`(**1**)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't, as it wasn't started under a utility such as screen or nohup; the process is locked into your tty at this point and can't be transferred to another as myisamcheck has no built-in facility for pausing it's operation mid-run. I've often wished I could do this with many tasks that I didn't realize were going to take hours...